# How to open a remote mysql connection?

Tags: mysql, go

I'm trying to connect to remote mysql database using go and the database/sql package.
I find the go/mysql documentation confusing. It seems there is no single example how to connect to a remote host. Like everyone would use localhost.
So far I have this

```
   import (
        "database/sql"
        _ "github.com/ziutek/mymysql/godrv"    
        db, err := sql.Open("mymysql", "tcp:"+dbHost*dbName+"/"+user+"/"+pass)
        defer db.Close()
```

Based on the docs from https://github.com/ziutek/mymysql

```
[PROTOCOL_SPECFIIC*]DBNAME/USER/PASSWD
//
// where protocol specific part may be empty (this means connection to
// local server using default protocol). Currently possible forms:
//   DBNAME/USER/PASSWD
//   unix:SOCKPATH*DBNAME/USER/PASSWD
//   unix:SOCKPATH,OPTIONS*DBNAME/USER/PASSWD
//   tcp:ADDR*DBNAME/USER/PASSWD
//   tcp:ADDR,OPTIONS*DBNAME/USER/PASSWD
```

I also tried

```
 db, err := sql.Open("mymysql", "tcp:"+dbHost, dbName+"/"+user+"/"+pass)
```

and it's not working either. The whole syntax seems cryptic.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

These sites are both really helpful in understanding Go SQL: https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql/ (even if you are using a different driver) and http://go-database-sql.org/

There are a few things that might help:

1. The connection string for `sql.Open()` is in DSN format.  `db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "<username>:<pw>@tcp(<HOST>:<port>)/<dbname>")` works for me for my connections.  Check the use of parenthesis for TCP connections.
2. The driver you are using has the command `mysql.New()` which can open connections using the format you've listed above: `db := mysql.New(proto, "", addr, user, pass, dbname)`
3. Confusingly, `sql.Open` doesn't actually open a connection, it just creates a db resource. You can verify that it's working by running `db.Ping()`

Comment: Using the URI you suggested I get " Wrong database part of URI". Is DNS absolutely required ? Doesn't really make sense...

Comment: DSNs usually don't require a DB name.  I'd check to see what that library you're using requires. I've been using a different library.

Comment: nevermind, it is working ... I was using the old lib ( ziutek ). Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: zuitek link is 404

Answer (score 15):

Following statement works for me:

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "db_user:password@tcp(localhost:3306)/my_db")
```

)